# Drupal 7 EVA fields not rendered on unpublished nodes

Tags: views, nodes

In a node type with 3 EVA fields, if I unpublish the node, the node view tab shows only the pink watermark "Unpublished" and the EVA fields are not rendered at all. The EVA related view does not have any publish filter nor any permission that prevents unpublished content to be rendered. All modules are updated to latest stable version. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the View Unpublished module. This is not related to EVA module but it is related to the drupal unpublished nodes built in user permissions